# SharePoint 2013 Language chooser from Site Settings

Tags: 2013, language-pack

I want to have the option to let the user choose the language from the site settings languages as it was in SharePoint 2010. Has anyone did a wsp or did a change in the .ascx page?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 you can only switch the language by changing the preferred browser language, there is no option available in the UI as in SP 2010.Also make sure you have enabled the desired language for the site by going to Site Settings-->Language Settings. Check the desired language which you want to enable in Alternate Language section.
See below blog about the same
http://olafd.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/switch-language-in-sharepoint-2013/

Also below is a link to blog which has a tweak to implement the 2010 type Language selector
http://islamkhattab.blogspot.in/2013/04/in-sharepoint-foundation-2010-when.html